# Building an setup project, Error 1001 (Something wrong with the Custom Actions)

Tags: c#, windows-installer

Pretty buffled by this. Is not the first time I'm building a setup- and never seen anything like this..

Basically, as soon as I add a custom action, and try to install, I get this error.

[image: bummer]

I do have an installer class in place with all the required code fields, and it's the same fields that I used in my previous installer classes.

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public partial class Installer : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
{


    public Installer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public override void Commit(IDictionary savedState)
    {
        base.Commit(savedState);
        // Do some work on commit 
    }
...
```

From Fuselogvw:

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (19/08/2012 @ 11:57:09) ***

The operation was successful.
Bind result: hr = 0x0. The operation completed successfully.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Windows\syswow64\MsiExec.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
LOG: Where-ref bind. Location = C:\Program Files (x86)\OrScanTechnologies\CamerasCalibrationApp\CamCalibApplication.exe
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Windows/syswow64/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = MsiExec.exe
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context.
WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\-\AppData\Local\Temp\CFGB105.tmp
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/OrScan Technologies/CamerasCalibrationApp/CamCalibApplication.exe.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\Program Files (x86)\OrScan Technologies\CamerasCalibrationApp\CamCalibApplication.exe
LOG: Entering run-from-source setup phase.
LOG: Assembly Name is: CamCalibApplication, Version=1.5.2.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
LOG: Re-apply policy for where-ref bind.
LOG: Where-ref bind Codebase does not match what is found in default context. Keep the result in LoadFrom context.
LOG: Binding succeeds. Returns assembly from C:\Program Files (x86)\OrScan Technologies\CamerasCalibrationApp\CamCalibApplication.exe.
LOG: Assembly is loaded in LoadFrom load context.
```

some more info from the fuselogvw 
[more http://s13.postimage.org/hqn04w1bb/Untitled2.png](http://s13.postimage.org/hqn04w1bb/Untitled2.png)

Answer (score 1):

Do a google search for Windows Installer XML (WiX) Deployment Tools Foundation (DTF) custom actions.  This is the gold standard for managed code custom actions and will eliminate the 1001 error messages.

That said, be sure to not be reinventing the wheel. Always use native Windows Installer standard tables and actions rather then rolling your own  out of process custom actions.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes, this kind of errors cause by mismatch of the projects platform target configuration. check that all your solution projects are AnyCPU/x64/x86 (whatever you like them to be).

Comment: Cheers for the quick reply. I don't think that's that though. The platform settings seem to be all good.

Comment: do you have a bit more specific log from the fuslogvw?
what is your platform target? and did you checked that all the projects target framework are the same?

Comment: My platform target is 'Any CPU' (I've tried with win32/x86 as well). All projects are either win32 or x86. I will edit my original message to include the bottom of the log ( I figured it's irrelevant). The thing is, there's no problem if I remove the CustomAction command..

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add 2 opencv dll files that somehow weren't added as dependencies. that done the trick.

Comment: There are about a dozen other failure modes inherint in InstallUtil custom actions that you simply haven't experienced yet.  Trust me, dump it and refactor the code using DTF.